# Recursive Binary Search does not return intended value

Tags: java, recursion, search, binary-search

My Recursive Java binary search algorithm is not working

This is my Method:

```
System.out.println("recursiveBinarySearch "+recursiveBinarySearch(x,0,x.length-1,10));


public static int recursiveBinarySearch(int[]array,int low,int high,int value){
    int mid;

    if(low<=high){
        mid=(low+high)/2;

        if(array[mid]<value){
            recursiveBinarySearch(array,mid+1,high,value);
        }else if(array[mid]>value){
            recursiveBinarySearch(array,low,mid-1,value);
        }else{
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It seems to always return -1, which means that the method failed to find the values. Could somebody please help me to fix this and get the right outcome?

Comment: Can you describe what NOT WOKING?

Comment: We need to see the `x` variable value. If the array is not ordered then use `Arrays.sort(x)` before using the method as otherwise the principle of a bindary search won't work.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: `recursiveBinarySearch(..)` -> `return recursiveBinarySearch(...)`

Comment: the out put is "recursiveBinarySearch -1"

Answer (score 2):

You should return the result of the recursive call:

```
public static int recursiveBinarySearch(int[]array,int low,int high,int value){
    int mid;
    if(low<=high){
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(array[mid]<value){
            return recursiveBinarySearch(array,mid+1,high,value);
        }else if(array[mid]>value){
            return recursiveBinarySearch(array,low,mid-1,value);
        }else{
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When you ignore the returned value of the recursive call, you always return `-1` (unless the initial `mid` index contains the value you are looking for).

Comment: noobie mistake
sorry!

Comment: This does not work with arrays with odd-numbered lengths

Comment: @JPadley I don't know why you say that. I just tried in with both odd and even lengths and it worked.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I don’t know what I was thinking. I mean that when you search for the value at the first index, it returns -1 because the mid of 0 and 1 gets rounded up

Comment: @JPadley I just tried searching the value of the first index and got 0. And `(0+1)/2` is 0, not 1.

Comment: That’s odd, cause I don’t get that. There must be something wrong with what I’ve got, sorry!